# How to interact with already deployed smart contract after reloading it into remix

Tags: solidity, remix

After I have deployed a contract, I'm able to interact with the setter functions, as well as with the getter functions. However, after a day goes by, when i try to interact with the same contract again, that is still open and loaded on my remix I get a "pending" message when I try to set and change some variables like a different address. When I try to call a get function also nothing happens. I don't know how to interact with my deployed contract again.

When I reload the contract using the contract address "at address", it properly loads the contract if I select the right smart contract (containing the getter and setter functions) from the dropdown menu in the "deploy and run" page. However, the same problem occurs, that is: when i try to set a variable the transaction is not mined (pending indefinetly), and the call functions also dont read the data.

In order for me to move forward with my project I need to be able to access and interact with the contract if I need to change a variable which currently doesn't work...

Anyone has an idea how to solve this (probably trivial) problem? Thanks!